# NumberFormatException while converting a *binary* string to a number

Tags: java, binary, integer, number-formatting

So I have this binary string (32 chars corresponding to 32 bits):

```
 String s = "11111111110000011101110111011000";
```

When I try to convert it to a number, it throws a NumberFormatException:

```
 Integer.parseInt(s,2);
```

Could not figure out why. Any idea? The strange thing is if I replace the first bit in the string from the left (1) with a zero bit (0), then it works. The first bit is only for indicating the sign of the number, so I should not make any overflow of 4 bytes in here, right?

=================

**UPDATED QUESTION**: Thanks to everyone for the answers. I got it now; basically the parseInt() method CANNOT handle the sign bit and it assumes that the sign bit just represents the value as any other bit. So now the question is how to I convert such binary string to a signed INTEGER number? I know some of you suggested I use long, but in my situation I just need it to be an int (long to explain, but you can assume that).

Comment: because its binary, not an integer. if it were 1011, you'd expect 11, but you'd get 1,011

Comment: "long to explain" I see what you did there :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number that you're trying to parse is bigger than `2^31-1` ([max integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)), use Long instead:

```
String s = "11111111110000011101110111011000";
System.out.println(Long.parseLong(s, 2)); // 4,290,895,320
```

If you want to see what's the maximum value of an Integer you can do:

```
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE); // 2,147,483,647
```

Responding your *UPDATE* section, if you don't mind loosing information (which happens when you convert long to int) you can do:

```
String s = "11111111110000011101110111011000";
long l = Long.parseLong(s,2);
int i = (int)l;
System.out.println(i); // -4071976
```

Comment: Can you explain why it is bigger than 2^32 while the first bit (from the left) is only used to indicate the sign of the number?

Comment: @Simo not sure if I got what you asked - but I added a part to the answer that might explain it.

Comment: Hey alfasin. Got your answer. Thanks. Any idea of how to convert such binary string to an int (not to a long). It has something to do with my encoding for compression, so long numbers will not help with compression.

Comment: @Simo you cannot convert it to int without losing information. If you're okay with losing information then you can check the length of `s` and remove characters until you have a string of length 30 (you should rather avoid strings of length 31 - just to avoid the edge case of hitting 2^31). One way to do it would be as I stated above in the additional example.

Comment: He's not losing information - he has 32 bits, and wishes to interpret them as a signed int.

Comment: @Amadan removing a digit is considered as losing information. Unless he records it, there's no way to know, after the fact, if he removed a zero or a one.

Comment: `(int)` will not remove a digit from a 32-bit number; it will reinterpret the number as signed. `11111111110000011101110111011000` converts to `-4071976`, while `01111111110000011101110111011000` converts to `2143411672` - distinct values, no information lost.

Comment: How to handle if its exceeds max limit of Long too.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to parse a 32-bit number into an `Integer`, which can only have 31 bits and a sign. `parseInt` can't handle the sign bit; you need to give the sign as `+` or `-` (or nothing). Your number should be (if I haven't screwed up my conversion) `-4071976`, which *can* be parsed if you give it to `parseInt` as `-1111100010001000101000`, but *not* as `11111111110000011101110111011000`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Now my question is how to convert that binary string to an int number? In my app (has to do with encoding), I need it to be an int, so the first bit needs to represent the sign.

Comment: `(int)Long.parseLong(s, 2)` is `-4071976` (as a signed `int` as you want, not as `long`).

Answer (score 2):

As other people already mentioned, this binary string does not fit the 32-bit *singed* int. However since Java 8 you can parse it as unsigned int, which works perfectly!

```
String s = "11111111110000011101110111011000";
System.out.println(Integer.parseUnsignedInt(s, 2)); // -4071976
```

There are other useful unsigned math methods added in Java 8 as well.

Comment: Nice! I wasn't aware of this option!

Answer (score 0):

You are telling that you are trying to parse binay String

```
String s = "11111111110000011101110111011000";
```

But this value is out of Java integer range:

Integer is 32 bit and for Java, the range is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. But your input has the value which is out of the range. So you are getting the exception.

But long is having 64 bit and the range is –9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to
9 ,223,372,036,854,775,807. So you can use the below:

```
String s = "11111111110000011101110111011000";
Long.parseLong(s,2);//4290895320
```